# Rails 6 Association Between 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have following models in my Rails 6 app.

1. Doctor
2. Course (MBBS, MD, MS, PhD etc.)
3. Specialization (ENT, Ortho, etc)
4. Education

A doctor has many courses and a course has many doctors. I have modeled it as under

```
class Doctor
  has_many :educations
  has_many :courses, through: :educations
  ...
end

class Course
  has_many :educations
  has_many :doctors, through: :educations
  ...
end

class Education
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :course
end
```

I want the associate a specialization with post graduate course. I have modified Education & Specialization classes as under.

```
class Education
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :specialization
end

class Specialization
  has_many :educations
end
```

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Why do you need the Education model? Seems like you could just have Doctor <HABTM> Course

Comment: If I only have two models Doctor and Course then I can go for HABTM. The course may have a specialization. If a doctor is MBBS, MS then she will have a specialization in MS, say ENT. Hence I have have a through association.

Comment: I also want to add the year of course. These are reasons for choosing has_many through association.

Comment: Okay, that looks good to me then. You might also want to consider adding Specialization <HABTM> Course, as a specialization may only be applicable to particular courses - that might help you with validation.

Comment: Can't have HABTM between Specialization and Course.
Because specialization should be tracked back to a doctor. Doctor takes a course. If course is not MBBS then it has a specialization. In my code I want to point to a doctor record and get its course, year of passing ans specialization.
So if i have a HABTM then i cannot track a specialization back to a doctor.

Comment: Sure you can - Course HABTM Specialization, and Education has_one Specialization.

Comment: I can't. Because then I cannot say what is the specialization of a doctor. There are 3 models of interest.
Doctor
Course
Specialization

If I do what you say then, given a doctor instance, how do i figure out what is his MS specialization? Or what is the specialization course (MS, MD, PG Diploma)?